# Read Windows Product Name via REG.exe within a BAT script

Tags: batch-file, registry, cmd

How can I use reg.exe within a BAT or CMD script to fetch the Windows product name from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion (value: ProductName)?  I've tried the following code, but I'm unable to figure out how to get it to work...

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName") do echo Product is %%A
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong since I know it's possible to fetch registry data like this for other values.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the closing quote char `'` possibly (after `"ProductName"`)?

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ^
('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName"') ^
do echo Product is %%A %%B
```

At least, it helped *me* :).

---

**EDIT**

`%%B` was added for the complete name based on the OP's comment.

Comment: That isn't helping.  Instead of returning "Windows 7 Enterprise" it just returns "Windows"

Comment: Here is the solution:  I needed to concatenate A and B from the returned result...

`for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName"') do SET "WINV=%%A %%B"`